# Rails regex for specific pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I need to grab the first occurrence of this pattern `[some-file-name ci]` OR `[some-file-name-ci.yml ci]`

So far I'm able to create this pattern

```
CONFIG_FILE_PATTERN = /\[(\w*[ _-]ci|\w*[ _-]*\.yml ci|.\w*[ _-]*\.yml ci|.\w*[-_]\w*[ _-]*\.yml ci|\w*[-_]\w*[ _-]*\.yml ci|\w*[-_]\w*[ _-]*\w ci|.\w*[-_]\w*[ _-]*\w ci)\]/i.freeze
```

This works fine for all cases except when there are multiple hyphens (-) in the file name.

Examples:

```
[hello-ci.yml ci] # works fine for this
[hello.yml ci] # works fine for this
[hello ci] # works fine for this
[hello-world-ci.yml ci] # does not work for this as the file name now have multiple hyphens
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think all you need is `/\[([^\]\[]*ci)\]/i`. See a [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/OhT36d9OAtj2vG). Or, `/\[([^\]\[]*[ _-]ci)]/i` if there must be space, `_` or `-` before `ci`

Comment: Thank you, I do need a space between the filename and ci. The second one worked for me @Wiktor

Comment: This is the regex I posted, see the answer below, please consider accepting/upvoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/\[([^\]\[]*[ _-]ci)\]/i
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/9A6zNQiVi1bnXe)

**Details**

- `\[` - a `[` char
- `([^\]\[]*[ _-]ci)` - Group 1:

  - `[^\]\[]*` - 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `[ _-]` - a space, `_` or `-`
  - `ci` - a `ci` substring
- `\]` - a `]` char.

A [Ruby test at IDEONE](https://ideone.com/BtDCeT) to extract the first occurrence:

```
s = '[hello-ci.yml ci] works fine for this [second-DONT-EXTRACT-hello-ci.yml ci]'
puts s[/\[([^\]\[]*[ _-]ci)\]/i, 1] # => hello-ci.yml ci
```